# Find the biggest digit

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
FUNCTION FBIG(N NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  R NUMBER; 
  M NUMBER;
  S NUMBER;

  BEGIN
  M := N;
  WHILE M>0 LOOP  
  R := MOD(M,10); 
  M := FLOOR(M/10);   
  S := GREATEST(R,M); 
   END LOOP;
 RETURN S;
  END FBIG;
END;
/

EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FBIG(47839));
```

Find the biggest digit if the 47839. 9 is the input value. I tried to take the last digit by MOD and remove the decimal by FLOOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your original code is not working is because a) your M will always be greater or equal to R until the very last loop (when M becomes 0), and b) you're not comparing the current value to the previous value of S.

Your code can be tweaked to work as follows:

```
FUNCTION fbig(n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  r NUMBER;
  m NUMBER;
  s NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  m := n;
  WHILE m > 0
  LOOP
    r := MOD(m, 10);
    m := floor(m / 10);
    s := greatest(r, s);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN s;
END fbig;
/
```

There are only two changes I needed to make, changing the greatest to check between s and r, and also to assign 0 to s right at the start (otherwise s will always be null, regardless of the value of r).

Comment: This has issues with negative and decimal inputs. `-1` will output `0` and `78.9` will output `8.9`. It will also output `0` if the input is `NULL`.

Comment: Good points; I’ll leave it up here so the OP can see this and work out how they could have written their code originally, but your answer is correct, esp if they want to pass in decimals or negative values.

Comment: Please note MT0’s comments regarding negative or decimal numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the requirement is not for negative or decimal points, its just pulling out the biggest number.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the number to a string in PL/SQL and test each character until you get to the decimal point:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FBIG(N NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  s CONSTANT VARCHAR2(4000) := TO_CHAR( n );
  c CHAR(1);
  m CHAR(1) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH( s ) LOOP
    c := SUBSTR( s, i, 1 );
    IF c = '.' THEN
      EXIT;
    ELSIF m IS NULL OR c > m THEN
      m := c;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN TO_NUMBER( m );
END FBIG;
/
```

Why your function does not work:

```
M := N;
WHILE M>0 LOOP  
  R := MOD(M,10); 
  M := FLOOR(M/10);   
  S := GREATEST(R,M); 
END LOOP;
```

You are overwriting `S` with each loop so the return value will only consider the most-significant digit as the previous ones will have been overwritten. So for `N = 47839.9` the steps it goes through are:

1. `R = 9.9, M = 4783, S = 4783`
2. `R = 3, M = 478, S = 478`
3. `R = 8, M = 47, S = 47`
4. `R = 7, M = 4, S = 7`
5. `R = 4, M = 0, S = 4`

and then it will return `4`.

How to fix your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FBIG(N NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  s NUMBER(1,0) := NULL;
  r NUMBER(1,0) := NULL;
  m NUMBER      := FLOOR( ABS( n ) );
BEGIN
  WHILE m > 0 LOOP
    r := MOD( m, 10 );
    IF s IS NULL OR r > s THEN
      s := r;
    END IF;
    m := ( m - r ) / 10;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN s;
END FBIG;
/
```

Comment: ThanQ MT0, there are compilation errors in the above function created

Comment: @CoreenStupka Fixed

Answer (score 1):

How about another approach? Split number to digits and select the largest of them:

```
SQL> create or replace function fbig (n number)
  2  return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select max(num)
  7    into retval
  8    from (select substr(to_char(n), level, 1) num
  9          from dual
 10          connect by level <= length(n)
 11         );
 12
 13    return retval;
 14  end;
 15  /

    Function created.

SQL> select fbig(47839) res1,
  2         fbig(125.774) res2
  3  from dual;

      RES1       RES2
---------- ----------
         9          7

SQL>
```

Comment: In this instance, I wouldn't go with a select statement to do the work; that introduces unnecessary context switching.

Comment: @Boneist, thank you for the comment. As usual, there are several ways to solve a problem; I chose this one (which doesn't have to be *the best*). It can (should?) be used in SQL only (i.e. no function at all) - just take the SELECT out of it and provide "n" as a parameter. As of context switching: yes, you're right, but - in this very case, I guess that nobody's going to see any difference.

Comment: Different answers are fine, but caveats should be specified if necessary so the OP can work out which one best suits their particular scenario. I agree that if this were a purely SQL based answer, yours is probably the one I would go with.